# MCSD: Web Applications certification and March 31, 2017

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm an ambitious millennial who has chosen to self-teach myself a few things that could obtain me success. One of them is software development - with two possible avenues for success - create my own website, and be my own boss. The other is - to get certified through Microsoft in my area of expertise and work for a company. My area of expertise? Well, I'll try to be quick here, I started learning ASP a long time ago, and then I learned ASP.NET WebForms, and then, most recently, I've learned and have gotten a pretty good grasp of ASP.NET MVC. So, my issue is this:

I've had my eye on doing this for a while now, and I noticed how Microsoft modifies its Exam's every year, so, every so often, I check on the MCSD testing page to see what's currently offered. At the time of this writing, what I'm interested in is becoming what's now, in December 2016, known as a Microsoft Certified Solutions Developer for Web Applications (the MCSD: Web Applications certification branch), but I just found out the certification expires on March, 31 2017.

The exact page that made me feel alarmed on the topic is - https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/learning/mcsd-web-apps-certification.aspx - and, the exact quote was "Note This certification will retire on March 31, 2017. When the certification retires, all individuals whose transcripts list this certification as active on or after September 26, 2016, will retain the active status. Find out about the replacement certification, MCSD: App Builder."

As I said, I'm ambitious, and have a few avenues I can pursue. Although, as I said, I've been interested in getting this certification for some time now, but, it's just that I've been busy doing many things, and I'm unsure if I can complete the exam by that date, and the new replacement certification branch (MCSD: App Builder) doesn't make sense to me, I want to develop with C# and MVC, and I don't want to have anything to do with Azure - which is what that new replacement branch is focused on - while the current branch that's available till March, 31 2017 - has a specific exam for MVC developers (Developing ASP.NET MVC Web Applications). I don't understand why Microsoft feels this change is necessary, this is alienating developers like myself. I don't know what to do, I wish there was something I am unaware of here, and there still will be some kind of exam offered specifically for MVC (I mean, since MVC was introduced, there's been an exam specifically for it - and now, they want to get rid of the focus on it altogether when it comes to certification? Maybe it's because Microsoft just made ASP.NET and MVC (under the new "Core" Framework) to be open source...)

***If anybody here has any reassuring information for me, or some kind of information that'd help in some way pertaining to this, I would really appreciate it.***

Comment: I'm not really sure if a question like this belongs here, but i've posted my answer anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have both MSCD: Web Apps and MSCD: App Builder.

Web apps is based around the older .NET 4.5 and 4.6 framework of doing things, where as App Builder is geared towards the .NET Core and .NET Standard upcomings.

I believe you only need to do 2 exams for App Builder itself, but you need to hold a certification lower then it (which is 1 exam), instead of the 3 exams for the Web apps cert.

Basically they have just moved the structure around a little bit to better adapt to their newer technologies coming out and to make it a little easier for people to get certifications.

Technically the MCSD: Web applications certification is only valid for 2 years anyways once you've achieved it.

The current MSCD: Web apps exam has been around for about 3 years or so, expect that they will be making changes like this every 3-5 years.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this definitely put things into perspective for me, and was very informative!